# Info on object attribute callout with or without brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you tell me why in the following code the same attribute I have to call it first with the brackets and then without?

For example `str(vendere[conta].valMax_cl` is without brackets, and if I put them in I would get an error flag. What is the logic behind this?

```
if prova < vendere[conta].valMax_cl():
    vendere[conta].valMax_cl = prova
    print(str(vendere[conta].posizione_cl()), str(vendere[conta].nome_cl()), 
              str(vendere[conta].valAcquisto_cl()), str(vendere[conta].valAttuale_cl()), 
              str(vendere[conta].valMax_cl))
    percento = (
        (float(vendere[conta].valMax_cl) - float(vendere[conta].valAcquisto_cl())) * 
         100 / float(vendere[conta].valAcquisto_cl()))
    print(percento)
```

Comment: If by "brackets" you mean parentheses `(` and `)`, they're needed to *call* the associated value which is usually a function or method, and in this case the result of any value returned will be converted into a `str`. Without them, the value itself will be converted.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. But Why only “ (float(vendere[conta].valMax_cl)” must Be without “( )”???

Comment: That's impossible to determine from what is posted in your question, which has no definition of the variable `vendere` — because its definition is _why_. However the inconsistent use of `()` in conjunction with `vendere[conta].valMax_cl` makes no sense regardless.